# Jquery where clause on json

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Say I have a sample json data like:

```
 var data = {
            "items": [{
                "id": 1,
                "category": ["cat1","cat2"]
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "category": ["cat1","cat3"]
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "category": ["cat11","cat2"]
            }]
        };
```

Now How to return only data which contains cat1

I have tried with jquery grep like

```
var returnedData = $.grep(data.items, function (element, index) {
return element.category.indexOf("cat1") == 1;
});
```

But it's not giving me correct output which should return first and second object.

Thanks.

Comment: `indexOf()` returns you the *index* of the element (starting at `0`) or `-1` if not found.  `1` is the 2nd position in the array, and none of the elements have `cat1` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns `index`(`0...n` - position in array) or `-1` if value does not exists in array. You need change condition to check `index` on `> -1.` In your variant you always check `index == 1`, but `cat1` has `index` 0 - that's why you get empty result.

```
var returnedData = $.grep(data.items, function (element) {    
  return element.category.indexOf('cat1') >= 0;
});
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/jihofe/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.filter`

```
var filteredData = data.items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.category.indexOf("cat1") > -1;
});
```